# C++ Template Variadic Class Constructor working with Parameter Pack but functions not

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

So the problem I am facing is that my Data Structure class `constructor` works allowing me to declare the class with variable length of `parameters`:

```
template<class T>
class Dynarray
{
    private:
        int size;
    public:
        template<class T, typename... Arguments>
        Dynarray(T item,Arguments...)
        {
            size = sizeof...(Arguments);
        }
}
```

However if I add the additional public member function so I can add more to the class like so:

```
template<class T>
class Dynarray
{
    private:
        int size;
    public:
        template<class T, typename... Arguments>
        Dynarray(T item,Arguments...)
        {
            size = sizeof...(Arguments);
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        template<class T, typename... Arguments>
        void Dynarray<T>::AddGroup(T item, Arguments...)
        {   //Errors C2838, C2059, C2334

            size += sizeof...(Arguments);

        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

I get error codes:

> C2838  'AddGroup': illegal qualified name in member declaration
>
> C2059  syntax error: '{'
>
> C2334  unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body

Is there a difference when it comes class templates between `Constructors` and `Member Functions` like this? Do you know of any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

Inside the class definition, you should not repeat `Dynarray<T>`:
so it should be:

```
template<typename... Arguments>
void AddGroup(T item, Arguments...)
{
    size += sizeof...(Arguments);
}
```

(I also remove the duplicate `typename T` which is already present for the class.)

Comment: Been working on this for the last week almost nonstop and you just saved my life. Thank you so much!